# oracle sql error Case When Then Else

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
SELECT * 
FROM   FirstTable
WHERE  RowProcessed = 'N'
AND    (
        CASE
            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT top 1 FROM SecondTable)
            THEN 1
            ELSE EXISTS(
                         SELECT SecondTable.RowProcessed 
                         FROM   SecondTable 
                         WHERE  FirstTable.Key = SecondTable.Key
                         AND    SecondTable.RowProcessed = 'Y'
                       )
        END
       )
AND OtherConditions
```

Case When then else in where clause. Not sure about the syntax.

I would like to verify there are rows in the SecondTable and if there are rows check for another condition, that is basicallly what I want to do.

Comment: There is no `TOP` in Oracle. Please read the manual

Comment: why don't you just use an OR clause between your two `EXISTS` ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want? If there are rows in SecondTable, then do the second `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * FROM FirstTable
WHERE RowProcessed = 'N'
AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 from SecondTable)
      OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SecondTable
                 WHERE FirstTable.Key = SecondTable.Key
                   and SecondTable.RowProcessed = 'Y'))
AND OtherConditions
```